# Is there jwt authentication for aiohttp?

Tags: python, jwt, aiohttp

I have django backend with JWT authentication and want to work on client side using aiohttp. I didn't found any ready-made implementations. All I found is `aiohttp-jwt`, which used on server side. For example, for `requests` there is `requests-jwt`, which is intended to use on client side. Should I write own workaround?

Comment: It sounds like you might not understand how JWT auth works fully. Could you explain exactly what you are looking for on the client side when it comes to JWT auth?

Comment: @infecting I am looking for ready implementation of authentication with jwt for aiohttp on client side